# How to use the && operator in Perl

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and  am trying to use the following code to execute a print statement if it satisfies two conditions.

```
if ($ARGV[0] eq "test") && ($ARGV[1] eq "test1"){
print"test and test1 Selected\n"
}
```

How can I adjust the code such that it does not throw any errors?

Comment: See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) also.

Comment: put the first and second condition inside () within the if statement

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax for the `if` statement is:

```
if (CONDITION) BLOCK
```

so if your condition is

```
($ARGV[0] eq "test") && ($ARGV[1] eq "test1")
```

then you'd use

```
if (($ARGV[0] eq "test") && ($ARGV[1] eq "test1")) { ... }
```

That said, those parens are not needed because `&&` is meant to be used exactly like that.

```
if ($ARGV[0] eq "test" && $ARGV[1] eq "test1") { ... }
```

---

I don't know why the other two suggested disguising `&&` with the lower-precedence `and`. There's a reason symbols are used to for separators (e.g. `,`, `;`, `{ ... }`, etc) and it's because it makes it easier to find boundaries in the code at a glance, improving readability.

As such, the most commonly-used convention by far is to use `or` and `and` for flow control (`or die`, `or next`, `or return`, etc.), and use `||` and `&&` in expressions (as you did).

Answer (score 4):

You may put these conditions **inside** of if-clause.

```
if (($ARGV[0] eq "test") && ($ARGV[1] eq "test1")) {
    print"test and test1 Selected\n"
}
```

*(So my making unnecessary addition with rough description about logical conjunction operators had some confusing problems and caused criticism that I removed it totally.)*

For your question here, I think that simply **nesting use of bracket** is the point.

Comment: `and` vs `&&` is irrelevant to the question at hand (they have differing precedence, but that's a moot point here, so it's a style point). The important part is the bracketing. I think your answer would be improved if you made that clearer.

Comment: @Sobrique Thank you for your advice. I've tried to improve my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: `and` is not generally preferred to `&&`; it's common to use `and` and `or` for flow control (e.g. `or die`), but you can't just replace all instances of `&&` and `||` with `and` and `or` willy-nilly. `$x = 1 and 0;` sets `$x` to 1; `$x = 1 && 0;` sets `$x` to 0. See the discussion in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-or-and-Exclusive-Or).

Comment: Also, `eq` and `==` do completely different things and are not interchangeable. `eq` is for string equality and `==` is for numeric equality. `1.0 == 1` is true, while `'1.0' eq '1'` is false.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes, actually they are not the same. So I think this question case is boolean context (determining boolean true or false result) and apparently not for flow controlling. I read in some book, because `and` has lower priority, it is *safer* to avoid bugs. Excuse me of my degression...